# Is it possible to create c++ project in the new visual studio code for mac?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio

Seems to be missing as a file type in new files, do I need to add some kind of extension or something? I know I can create .cpp files but I'm not sure how to build and run them with the gcc once I do. Documentation seems to be difficult to find, as the web is cluttered with VSCode docs, and VS for Windows docs.

**Edit**
I know you normally select it as a solution type. It is not available as a solution type.

Comment: You create a new solution/project, not choose it as a file type (unless I'm missing something here).

Comment: @cybermonkey it is not available as a solution type (https://puu.sh/uUSUc/8a7065d111.png) Is there a way to add solution types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why people voted this down. The correct answer is **no, you cannot create or run c++ projects in Visual Studio for macOS beta at this time.**